# python and using 'self' in methods

Tags: python, self

From what I read/understand, the 'self' parameter is similiar to 'this'.

Is that true?

If its optional, what would you do if self wasnt' passed into the method?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's used in similar ways.  Note that it's a positional parameter and you can call it what you want; however there is a strong convention to call it `self` (not `this` or anything else).  Some positional parameter *must* be there for a usable instance method; it is not optional.

Comment: "It must be there" might suggest to the uninitiated that _It_ is `self`. I'd like to clarify that, the first parameter must be there and will point to an instance of the object. It is called `self` by convention but if you write code for an obfuscated coding contest you _could_ call it something different.

Answer (score 3):

**The joy of Python**

That is true to some extend. Methods are **bound** to the object instance they are a part of. When you see

`def some_func(self, foo, bar)`

The passing of self is *sometimes* implicit when you call, for example:

`obj.some_func(foo_val, bar_val)`

Which is equal (presuming `obj` is of class `MyClass`) to

`MyClass.some_func(obj, foo_val, bar_val)`

Because the method is bound to `obj`, the `self` argument gets populated. This is part of Python being explicit with what it means. In other languages, `this` just pops into scope, with Python there is some exposure of how this happens.

You can also pass methods around, and manually pass them `self` when not calling from a bound context.

[The Python docs do a good Job](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html):

```
xf = x.f
while True:
   print xf()
```

> will continue to print hello world until the end of time.
>
> What exactly happens when a method is called? You may have noticed that x.f() was called >without an argument above, even though the function definition for f() specified an >argument. What happened to the argument? Surely Python raises an exception when a function >that requires an argument is called without any — even if the argument isn’t actually >used...
>
> Actually, you may have guessed the answer: the special thing about methods is that the >object is passed as the first argument of the function. In our example, the call x.f() is >exactly equivalent to MyClass.f(x). In general, calling a method with a list of n arguments >is equivalent to calling the corresponding function with an argument list that is created >by inserting the method’s object before the first argument.

Answer (score 2):

`self` is `this`, just you have to explicitly pass it and explicitly use it to refer to class methods/properties.

It isn't optional in class methods. You will get a `TypeError` if you try to define a classmethod without at least one argument (i.e., the `self` parameter).

However, you can call it something other than `self`, but I have never seen otherwise.

Comment: You should rephrase.  [`classmethod`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod) is something different.

Answer (score 0):

In classes a `self` variable (or `cls` for classmethods) is required. What you want to call it is your decision though. If you prefer you could call it `this` instead.

A `classmethod` is a method that gets the `class` as a first argument instead of a instance. It can be called without passing an instance.
i.e. with a `classmethod` you can do:

```
SomeObject.some_class_method()
```

while a normal method would require you to do

```
SomeObject().some_normal_method()
or
SomeObject.some_normal_method(instance)
```

Comment: No, in Python [static methods](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod) are different.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen is correct.  A class method receives a reference to the class as its first parameter, a static method has no required parameters.

Answer (score 0):

`self` refers to the object on which the method was called, much like `this` in C++. But it is important that `self` is merely a *convention*, you can name it as you like and pass instances of subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

`self` is definitely similar to `this`, however, in Python, the name `self` is just a convention, and could be named anything else. The variable is named after whatever you call it in the function's prototype (`def function(whatever, params...):`).

For instance methods, `self` IS actually required. For class or static methods, you need to specify that they should be treated as such, and then `self` is not required. For example:

```
def type_to_display(type):
    """Converts a pass type to the full written pass type."""
    return list((pair[1] for pair in Pass.TYPE_CHOICES if pair[0] ==      
                          type[0:1].upper()))[0]                          
type_to_display = staticmethod(type_to_display)
```

You will never be able to use an instance method in such a way that self is not passed in. For example, if I have an instance `my_car` of a `Car` class, and I use the `Car` class's `drive` instance method, the `my_car` instance will be implicitly passed into the `drive` method as the first parameter (`self`).

```
class Car:
    def drive(self):
        self.do_some_stuff()

my_car = Car()
my_car.drive() # actually calls Car.drive(my_car)
```