# Why do functions/methods in python need self as parameter?

Tags: python, methods, self

I can understand why it is needed for local variables, (*self.x*), but why is is nessecary as parameter in a function? Is there something else you could put there instead of self?

Please explain in as much layman terms as possible, I never had decent programming education.

Comment: The name `self` is the convention; but you can flaunt the convention and use a different name if you really wanted to.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained

Comment: There are a long list of possible duplicates here: [Python 'self' explained](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2709821), [How to avoid explicit 'self'?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1984104), [python and using 'self' in methods](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3283178) and [Explaining the python 'self' variable to a beginner](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6990099)

Comment: `self` refers to object itself .

Answer (score 4):

If you consider it, EVERY programming language does that - or, at least, the most common languages like pascal, c++ or java do). EXCEPT that, in most programming languages, the `this` keyword is assumed and not passed as a parameter. Consider the function pointers in those languages: they're different than method-pointers.

Pascal:

```
function(a: Integer): Integer;
```

vs

```
function(a: Integer): Integer of object;
```

The latter considers the `self` pointer (yes, it's named `self` but it's an implicit pointer like the `this` in c++, while the python `self` is explicit).

C++:

```
typedef int (*mytype)(int a);
```

vs

```
typedef int Anyclass::(*mytype)(int a);
```

As difference with Pascal, in C++ you must specify the class owning the method. Anyway, this method pointer declaration states the difference between a function expecting a `this` or not.

But Python takes seriously it's [Zen](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), as quichua people takes seriously their Ama Suway, Ama Llullay, Ama K'ellay:

```
Explicit is better than implicit.
```

So, that's why you see *explicitly* the `self` parameter (and must write it, of course) for instance methods and `@classmethod`s (althought it's usually called `cls` there since it's intention is to dynamically know the class and not the instance). Python does not assume a `this` or `self` keyword must exist inside the methods (so, the namespace has only true variables - remember you are NOT forced to name them `self` or `cls` althought it's usual and expected).

Finally, if you get:

```
x = AClass.amethod #unbound method
```

You must call it as

```
x(aninstance, param, param2, ..., named=param, named2=param2, ...)
```

While getting it as:

```
x = anInstance.method #bound method, has `im_self` attribute set to the instance.
```

must be called as:

```
x(param, param2, ..., named=param, named2=param2, ...)
```

Yes, the `self` is explicit in the parameter list since it's not assumed a keyword or 'backdoor' must exist, but not in the argument list because of syntactic sugar every OOP language has (weird criteria, huh?).

Answer (score 4):

By default, every function declared in the namespace of a class assumes that its first argument will be a reference to an instance of that class. (Other types of functions are decorated with `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod` to change this assumption.) Such functions are called methods. By convention, Python programmers name that first parameter `self`, but Python doesn't care what you call it. When a method is called, you must provide that reference. For example (with `self` replaced by `foobar` to demonstrate that `self` is not the required name):

```
class A:
    def __init__(foobar):
        foobar.x = 5

    def somefunc(foobar, y):
        print foobar.x + y

a = A()
print A.somefunc(a, 3)   # Prints 8
```

Python provides some syntactic sugar to make the link between an object and a method called on it more obvious, by letting you call a bound method instead of the function itself. That is, `a.somefunc(3)` and `A.somefunc(a, 3)` are equivalent. In Python terminology, `A.somefunc` is an unbound method, since it still needs an instance when it is called:

```
f = A.somefunc
print f(a, 3)
```

By contrast, `a.somefunc` is called a bound method, since you have already provided the instance to use as the first argument:

```
f = a.somefunc
print f(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's how Python's implementation of object oriented programming works -- a method of an instance (a so-called *bound method*) is called with that instance as its first argument.

Besides variables of the instance (`self.x`) you can also use it for anything else, e.g. call another method (`self.another_method()`), pass this instance as a parameter to something else entirely (`mod.some_function(3, self)`), or use it to call this method in the superclass of this class (`return super(ThisClass, self).this_method()`).

You *can* give it an entirely different name as well. Using `pony` instead of `self` will work just as well. But you shouldn't, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `self` for the first reference in a method is entirely convention.

You can call it something else, even inconsistently in the same class:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(notself, i):
        notself.i=i             # note 'notself' instead of 'self'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.i)      # back to the convention   

f=Foo(22)

print f
```

But please don't do that. It is confusing to others that may read your code (or yourself when you read it later).